# Binding with ElementName in the nested UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following simple code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        x:Name="WindowInst" …>
        <local:UserControl1/>
</Window>
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1" …>
    <Button Content="Click me"
        Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonClickedCommand,
                        ElementName=WindowInst}" Height="134" Width="314" />
</UserControl>
```

And in the ViewModel for the Window I have ButtonClickedCommand:

```
#region Avatar click command
RelayCommand _buttonClickedCommand;
public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_buttonClickedCommand == null)
        {
            _buttonClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.ButtonClicked());
        }
        return _buttonClickedCommand;
    }
}

public void ButtonClicked()
{
}
#endregion
```

Unfortunately, it causes exception at runtime:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=WindowInst'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.ButtonClickedCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

Could you explain me what’s wrong with it?

Comment: could you show where you set the DataContext?

Comment: For instance, in the window DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, ElementName=WindowInst}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying your binding as follows...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        x:Name="WindowInst" …>
        <local:UserControl1/>
</Window>
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication3.UserControl1" …>
    <Button Content="Click me"
        Command="{Binding Path=ButtonClickedCommand, Mode=FindAncestor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Height="134" Width="314" />
</UserControl>
```

This should work as `WindowInst` does not live within `Self` since your container is the `UserControl`; which is being placed within the `Window`. In addition you need to make sure that you are setting your `DataContext` within the `Window` or its value will be `null` and no binding will ever occur no matter if your syntax is accurate or not.

Comment: yes, i know that it will work. Perhaps, I didn't explain my problem clear. I wrote this code as a demonstration, in reality I have more complicated code in a big real world application. So I don't have a window in this real world application - i have 2 UserControls A and B.  A contains B. A works fine with binding like mine. B contains A so I supposed that the same binding should work in B, but it didn't.

Comment: oh, I catch it! I can write RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your bindings are a little off.

Please see [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands) on WPF command binding.

As a general rule, specify as little as possible in your bindings. I don't think you need element name in this circumstance and datacontext is the assumed root of your bindings.

Comment: CommandBindings can only be used with methods in code behind. As far as I use MVVM i have no code behind and all my methods are in the ViewModel